# How to use case statement that fetch data on date basis in where clause in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server

Please help me out in finding the solution.

I want to display yesterday's max price of the commodity, if there is no entry for yesterday then day before yesterday's max price.

Below is my SQL server query. I am using SQL Server 2012 Management Studio

```
SELECT 
    MARKETNAME, COMMODITY, MAXPRICE
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY commodity ORDER BY maxprice DESC) rn
     FROM 
         markets 
     WHERE
         date = (DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 1, GETDATE()), 0)
    ) X
WHERE 
    rn = 1
```

This query displays yesterday's max price of commodity if none of the commodity was sold yesterday, the query result will be empty Instead this I want to display day before yesterday's maxprice.

For example: If yesterday Rice commodity sold for 4000 and day before yesterday it sold for 5000. Then it should display yesterday's maxprice not day before yesterday.

How could I achieve that?

Comment: Remove the where clause and add `order by rn`. The query will then display in the first row, the most recent maxprice record without regard for which day that represents.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i need based on date only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the inner `SELECT` you'll have only rows from yesterday because `date = (DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 1, GETDATE()), 0)` in the `WHERE` clause. You also need to allow the day before yesterday. Add something like `OR date = (DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 2, GETDATE()), 0)` to that `WHERE` clause. Then add `Date DESC,` to the sort before  `MaxPrice`, so that the youngest has an `rm` of 1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But now its comparing two dates. I need day before Yesterday's data if and only if there is no entry for yesterday

Comment: For example: If yesterday Rice commodity sold for 4000 and day before yesterday it sold for 5000. Then it should display yesterday's maxprice not day before yesterday.